# How to install SSL certificate if my website is hosted using Github pages and the domain is from Hostinger?

Tags: github, ssl-certificate, github-pages, web-hosting

Unable to install ssl certificate on Github.

I have tried creating a folder 'ssl' and pasted two certificates and the private key file but still the github page didn't the Enforce HTTPS checkbox is disabled. Please help me to install ssl certificate on github pages.

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. Please delete your question here and re-ask it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't install an SSL certificate on a website hosted on GitHub Pages if your custom domain is from Hostinger.

However, there may be a workaround that you can use to enable HTTPS. You can use a free CDN service like **CloudFlare** to add SSL encryption to your website.

You will need to sign up for a free CloudFlare account and enable their "[Flexible SSL" option](https://developers.cloudflare.com/ssl/origin-configuration/ssl-modes/flexible/). This will encrypt traffic between the visitors and Cloudflare, but not between Cloudflare and GitHub Pages.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to install a custom SSL certificate on Github. While you can use HTTPS for Github Pages repositories, it's important to note that the SSL certificate used by Github is automatically generated and only valid for subdomains of github.io. Therefore, you cannot use your own SSL certificate on Github Pages.

If you want to host a website with a custom SSL certificate, I recommend using a hosting provider that supports custom SSL and setting up your website there. There are many hosting providers available that support custom SSL, including Amazon Web Services, Google Cloud Platform, DigitalOcean, and others.

If you want to use Github to host a website and ensure that communications with the site are secure, you can use the subdomain provided by Github, which already has a valid SSL certificate. To enable HTTPS on a Github Pages repository, simply go to the repository settings, select the "Enforce HTTPS" option, and wait a few minutes for Github to provision the SSL certificate for your site's subdomain.